# std::tr1::mem_fn return type

Tags: c++, std, tr1

I want to put the result of this:

```
std::tr1::mem_fn(&ClassA::method);
```

Inside a variable, what is the type of this variable ?

That will look something like this:

```
MagicalType fun = std::tr1::mem_fn(&ClassA::method);
```

Also, what is the result type of `std::tr1::bind` ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return types of both `std::tr1::mem_fn` and `std::tr1::bind` are unspecified.

You can store the result of `std::tr1::bind` in a `std::tr1::function`:

```
struct ClassA { 
    void Func() { }
};

ClassA obj;
std::tr1::function<void()> bound_memfun(std::tr1::bind(&ClassA::Func, obj));
```

You can also store the result of `std::tr1::mem_fn` in a `std::tr1::function`:

```
std::tr1::function<void(ClassA&)> memfun_wrap(std::tr1::mem_fn(&ClassA::Func));
```

Comment: I'm trying to use `std::tr1::function<void(MyType*)> fun =
        std::tr1::mem_fn(&ClassA::method);` but it doesn't compile, what's wrong ?

Comment: @Tarantula:  The callable object returned by `mem_fn` takes a reference, not a pointer.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work, my prototype for Func is: virtual void Func(MyType *argument) = 0;

Comment: @Tarantula:  If it is a member function that takes an argument, then the resulting callable object will take two arguments:  a reference to the object on which to call the member function and the pointer to pass as the argument to the member function.  In that case, it would be a `function<void(ClassA&, MyType*)>`.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of `mem_fn` and `bind` is *unspecified*. That means, depending on the arguments a different kind of object is returned, and the standard doesn't prescribe the details how this functionality must be implemented.

If you want to find out what the type is in a particular case with a particular library implementation (for theoretical interest, I hope), you can always cause an error, and get the type from the error message. E.g:

```
#include <functional>

struct X
{
    double method(float);
};

int x = std::mem_fn(&X::method);

9 Untitled.cpp cannot convert 'std::_Mem_fn<double (X::*)(float)>' to 'int' in initialization
```

In this case, note that the type's name is reserved for internal use. In your code, you shouldn't use anything with a leading underscore (and a capital letter).

In C++0x, I suppose the return type would be `auto` :)

```
auto fun = std::mem_fn(&ClassA::method);
```

Answer (score 0):

The function could be implemented in the following way (you thus also see the return type): You can try this piece of code here http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/. Unfortunately, it makes use of variadic templates https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template which are only part of the C++11 standard.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class R, class T, class... Args > class MemFunFunctor
{
  private:
  R (T::*mfp)(Args... ); //Pointer to a member function of T which returns something of type R and taking an arbitrary number of arguments of any type 

public:
  explicit MemFunFunctor(R (T::*fp)(Args... ) ):mfp(fp) {}

  R operator()(T* t, Args... parameters)
  {
      (t->*mfp)(parameters... );
  }

};

template <class R,class T, class... Args> MemFunFunctor<R,T,Args... > my_mem_fn( R (T::*fp)(Args... ) )
{
    return MemFunFunctor<R,T,Args... >(fp);   
}


class Foo //Test class
{
    public:
        void someFunction(int i, double d, const std::string& s )
        {
            std::cout << i << " " << d << " " << s << std::endl;
        }
};


int main() //Testing the above code
{

    Foo foo;
    auto f = my_mem_fn(&Foo::someFunction);

    f(&foo, 4, 6.7, "Hello World!" ); //same as foo.someFunction(4, 6.7, "Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some comments/description for your code?